# In visual studio code console log does not print raw data but in terminal works?

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, visual-studio-code

[image]

```
  var fs = require('fs');

  fs.readFile(process.argv[1], function callBack(err, data){
      if(err){
        return;
      }
      console.log('raw data ::', data);
      console.log('string ::', data.toString());
  })
```

Output does not even print 'raw data ::' line.

Comment: it is working and showing `raw data`.try adding `throw err ` instead of return

Comment: In visual studio code editor its not working but in terminal its working fine.

Comment: Please Add a schreenshot of the logs

Comment: added @vibhor1997a

Answer (score 2):

You can debug with external terminal by configuring `launch.json` (You need to place your file inside a folder to do configuration)

Go to `Debug -> Open Configurations`

Add `"console": "externalTerminal"` to your `launch.json`

Example edited file

```
"version": "0.2.0",
"configurations": [
    {
        "type": "node",
        "request": "launch",
        "name": "Launch Program",
        "program": "${workspaceFolder}/t.js",
        "console": "externalTerminal"
    }
]
```

Try Debugging. VsCode will debug your output on separate terminal

Hope it helped you.

Comment: Didn't you get separate terminal for output?

Comment: it debugs the code by launching separate terminal and works fine.

Comment: it maybe a bug of vscode or sometimes they are limiting the stdout. I suggest you to open an issue for [vscode](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode)